# bind a jquery function to fancybox .close() event

Tags: jquery, function, fancybox, bind

I would like to trigger a simple jQuery function based on a fancybox closing. it is the only fancybox on the page

```
$.fn.fancybox.close = function() {
    $('#sub_cont').hide(250, function() {
    $('#IDsearchform input').val('');
    });
 });
```

ofcourse the above doesn't work

Comment: how about when you initialize the fancybox using the onClosed option?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Update: **
Please take a note of @mathoiland's answer, "It looks like Fancybox 2 deprecated the onClosed callback. It now uses afterClose." if you are using FancyBox 2.x

Pass the onClosed option to the fancybox function.

i.e:

```
$("<YOUR-SELECTOR>").fancybox({
  onClosed: function() {
    $('#sub_cont').hide(250, function() {
    $('#IDsearchform input').val('');
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: thanks it's  works fine for me :-)  but you need to add single quotes like this 'onClosed'

Comment: `onClosed` depreciated please use  `afterClose`

Comment: @Ajmal Did you care you read the post, where I mentioned that the solution I proposed (which was valid at the time I answered the question), is now deprecated and to check matthoiland's answer? Am not sure why you still thought that the answer shd be downvoted..not that I care...

Answer (score 34):

Just a note. It looks like Fancybox 2 depreciated the onClosed callback. It now uses afterClose.

See the new documentation under 'Callbacks'. http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Answer (score 18):

In latest version of fancybox you might need to use 'afterClose' in place of 'onClosed'

so this code..

```
$("<YOUR-SELECTOR>").fancybox({
  onClosed: function() {
    $('#sub_cont').hide(250, function() {
    $('#IDsearchform input').val('');
    });
  })
});
```

should become ...

```
$("<YOUR-SELECTOR>").fancybox({
  afterClose: function() {
    $('#sub_cont').hide(250, function() {
    $('#IDsearchform input').val('');
    });
  })
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#myfancybox").fancybox({
    'onClosed'  : function() {
             $('#sub_cont').hide(250, function() {
                $('#IDsearchform input').val('');
             });
    }
});
```